Resuming a failed download on Tizen Samsung Smart TV
We are building a Tizen web app but this should be relevant to native apps or .NET apps as well.
We download files using:
var downloadRequest = new tizen.DownloadRequest(url, path);
var downloadId = tizen.download.start(downloadRequest, downloadListener);

Due to poor internet connectivity at some sites the downloads can fail to complete. If you run the same code on the same download file it does not resume the download but starts at 0. On a poor internet connection the restarts could consume huge amounts of data due to the large size of the files. On a mobile capped connection this can cause large bills and/or blocked connections due to hitting the cap.
There is a .resume function but it’s purpose is to resume user paused downloads. It does not function as a resumable download function.
I tested by starting a large download and kill the app part way. I then started the download again and it started from 0 but this time because the file existed and it named it filename(1).ext.
My question is, how do I resume a failed download from the last position?

WebApplication does not allow to have pending downloads after its termination. Download deamon only alows to resume downloads started during the same application execution.
If you proceed the scenario:

Start downloading a big file and save id.
Disable wifi and wait for download error.
Use id from 1st point and call tizen.download.resume(id) to resume a download since the failed partial download.

I've checked above scenario using this code:
var listener =
{
  onprogress: function(id, receivedSize, totalSize)
  {
    console.log("Received with id: " + id + ", " + receivedSize + "/" + totalSize);
  },
  oncompleted: function(id, path)
  {
    console.log("Completed with id: " + id + ", path: " + path);
  },
  onfailed: function(id, error)
  {
    console.log("Failed with id: " + id + ", error name: " + error.name);
  }
};

var wifiDownloadRequest = new tizen.DownloadRequest(
    "http://download.tizen.org/tools/archive/14.02.2/Ubuntu_12.04/qemu_1.6.0rc3.orig.tar.gz",
    "downloads", null, "WIFI");

var downloadId_wifi = tizen.download.start(wifiDownloadRequest, listener);


//// -- Download starts --
//// Received with id: 1, 63464/14464394
//// Received with id: 1, 235696/14464394
//// ...
//// -- Disable wifi and download fails --
//// Failed with id: 1, error name: UnknownError

//// -- Enable wifi and download restart --
tizen.download.resume(1)
//// -- Download restarts --
//// Received with id: 1, 1350449/14464394
//// Received with id: 1, 1572825/14464394
//// ...

I guess that it should cover most cases of slow network. If the application is terminated in the meantime (point 2 == application terminate), then unfortunately downloading the file again after restart will start download since the beginning.
I didn't test it, but maybe you could use downloading in the service application to prevent it from being interrupted by accidental close of GUI application.

would you read this page? https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/connectivity-and-wireless/contents-downloads
downloadId = tizen.download.start(downloadRequest, listener);
tizen.download.resume(downloadId);
If the current state is PAUSED, CANCELED, or FAILED, calling the resume() method changes the download state to DOWNLOADING or QUEUED.

Yes I have. The .pause, .resume and .cancel functions can be used when you build a user interface that allows the user to pause, resume or cancel downloads. It does not resume partial failed downloads. Note the .resume function requires a downloadId that you get when you start the download. In this case if I download the same file again it will create new files with (1), (2), (3) etc. in the file name to make it unique. So the downloadId is not related to the failed partial download, it is the new download. So this function is not usable to resume a partial failed file.

Reference: https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/api-references/tizen-web-device-api-references/download-api.html
